# Antenna plugin - bracket being inserted

Tags: plugin, debugging, video, antenna

I'm using the Antenna plugin to display a YouTube video on a website. The strange thing is that there's a close bracket ')' being inserted after the video.

I can't for the life of me figure out where it's coming from as there are no closing brackets in the template anywhere.

Here's a link to the page (click on the video on the right-hand side): http://dev.whelanservices.com/pest-prevention

Here's the code:

```
<div id="pest-prevention-video">
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-area">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="videos" dynamic="no" status="open" entry_id="57"}
            {exp:antenna url='{video_url}' max_width="900" max_height="" cache_minutes="120" youtube_rel="0"}
                {embed_code}
            {/exp:antenna}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a client mention it a couple of days ago. That code is actually coming directly from Youtube's embed code. I reported it to Google yesterday but they don't seem to care. If you go to any Youtube video > Share > Embed you'll see it right after the closing iframe tag.

Comment: Is there anything we could do to hide it?

Comment: Looks like Youtube finally fixed it. I don't see the issue on my client's site anymore.